# Supervisord listener: Execute a symfony command each 10 minutes

Tags: python, php, symfony, supervisord

I'm trying to run a command every N minutes using a **supervisord** listener.
I have a listener that's subscribed to **TIC_60** event.

How can I delay the execution of my command, let's say for 10 mins.

**Supervisor Listener**

```
[eventlistener:my-listener]
command=/tmp/my-listener.py php /var/www/symfony/bin/console my-symfony-command
events=TICK_60
```

**Listener script**

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys
import subprocess

def write_stdout(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()

def write_stderr(s):
    sys.stderr.write(s)
    sys.stderr.flush()

def main(args):
    while 1:
        write_stdout('READY\n') # transition from ACKNOWLEDGED to READY
        line = sys.stdin.readline()  # read header line from stdin
        write_stderr(line) # print it out to stderr
        headers = dict([ x.split(':') for x in line.split() ])
        data = sys.stdin.read(int(headers['len'])) # read the event payload
        res = subprocess.call(args, stdout=sys.stderr); # don't mess with real stdout
        write_stderr(data)
        write_stdout('RESULT 2\nOK') # transition from READY to ACKNOWLEDGED

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
    import sys
```

Comment: There is a reason why this document continues on for several pages beyond the example you copy/pasted: http://supervisord.org/events.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made my own solution using a listener in PHP and shared memory.
On the listener it's controlled the TICK_60 has been triggered 10 times, thus can be considered 10 minutes has passed.

The counter to control there is 10 triggered events is saved in shared memory.